# QML QQuickText: Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickextras

When I use `TumblerColumn` in my `Tumbler`, I get `QML QQuickText: Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling`, When I use `Tumbler` alone the error doesn't appear. I can't figure out what is the problem with `TumblerColumn`.

Here is my `Dialog` code

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Extras 1.2

Dialog {
    id: customTimerInputDialog
    title: "Custom timer"
    height: 150
    width: 300
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok | StandardButton.Cancel
    onAccepted: {

    }

    onRejected: {
        console.log("Rejected")
    }

    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text {
            text: "Timer"
            height: 40
        }

        Tumbler {
            id: tumbler
            TumblerColumn {
                model: 10
            }

            TumblerColumn {
                model: 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TumblerColumn (TumblerStyle.qml) [complete source code](https://gemfury.com/liri-browser/deb:liri-browser/-/content/opt/liri-browser/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/TumblerStyle.qml)

```
...
// line 294
property Component delegate: Item {
    implicitHeight: (control.height - padding.top - padding.bottom) / tumblerStyle.visibleItemCount

    Text {
        id: label
        text: styleData.value
        color: "#666666"
        opacity: 0.4 + Math.max(0, 1 - Math.abs(styleData.displacement)) * 0.6
        font.pixelSize: Math.round(TextSingleton.font.pixelSize * 1.25)
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
...
```

Error message
[image]

**UPDATE**

I get the same error with [Popup QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html)

```
Popup {
    id: popup
    x: 100
    y: 100
    width: 200
    height: 300
    modal: true
    focus: true
    closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent

    Tumbler {
        id: intervalPicker
        TumblerColumn {
            model: 10
        }

        TumblerColumn {
            model: 60
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does TumblerColumn have a source?

Comment: @dtech Sorry what is TumblerColumn source?

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. Isn't it?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto yes, but I'm not anchoring in my `TumblerColumn`

Comment: @julekgwa Could you please post source code of `TumblerColumn`?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Well someone is trying to do anchoring, how and why cannot be established without posting the relevant code.

Comment: `Dialog` is supposed to have only one child element (i.e. `contentItem`). Please note that `Dialog` itself does not lay out its children.

Comment: @dtech I'm not trying to anchor anything, I'm using the code from qt.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto `Tumbler` is inside `Column` I was debugging and put it outside of `Column` and forgot to put it back.

Comment: @julekgwa Source code of `Tumbler` please.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto I have updated the question

Comment: I'm not sure though, Please use another id instead of `tumbler` for the `Tumbler` element. Does it fix the problem?

Comment: I have changed the id, still doesn't work.

Comment: Please show your imports.

Comment: @derM see my updated question

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing Qt Quick Controls 1 and 2. In your Dialog/Popup you import 
`QtQuick.Controls 2.2` and `QtQuick.Extras 1.2`. Both imports define a `Tumbler`, but the one from Qt Quick Extras is made to work with Qt Quick Controls 1 (see the imports in TumblerStyle.qml).

If you want to use TumblerColumn and TumblerStyle, you have to use the Tumbler from Qt Quick Extras 1.2.

If you want to use the Tumbler from Qt Quick Controls 2, you cannot use any of the tumbler facility from Qt Quick Extras 1.2.

If you need to have both Qt Quick Extras 1.2 and Qt Quick Controls 2 imported in a qml file, you need to use the `as` qualifier:

```
import QtQuick.Extras 1.2 as Extra
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2 as Controls2

...
Extra.Tumbler 
{
...
}

Controls2.Tumbler 
{
...
}
...
```